# Differentiate between no results returned and end of rows for cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor

I'm trying to implement a cursor in MYSQL. Inside that cursor, I have a select statement that might or might not return any rows.

I'm facing a problem when that query does not return any rows.

According to the MYSQL documentation,

> `NOT FOUND`: Shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that begin with `'02'`. This is relevant within the context of cursors and is used to control what happens when a cursor reaches the end of a data set. If no more rows are available, a No Data condition occurs with SQLSTATE value `'02000'`. You can set up a handler for it or a NOT-FOUND condition to detect this condition. For another example, see [Section 13.6.6, “Cursors”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html). The `NOT FOUND` condition also occurs for `SELECT ... INTO` ***`var_list`*** statements that retrieve no rows.

My termination of the cursor is implemented as usual.

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
    FOR NOT FOUND SET FINISHED = 1;
```

The problem is that the termination is triggered because of the query inside the cursor returning 0 rows. Is there a way to differentiate between those two cases so that the cursor continues despite my query returning 0 results?

Thanks in advance.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CURSOR_PLACEHOLDER;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CURSOR_PLACEHOLDER()
BEGIN
DECLARE FINISHED INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CURRENT_ROW_ID VARCHAR(256);

DEClARE CURRENT_ROW
    CURSOR FOR
    SELECT ID
    FROM A
    WHERE ID_P IN (SELECT ID_P
                      FROM A
                      GROUP BY ID_P
                      HAVING COUNT(ID_P) > 1);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
    FOR NOT FOUND SET FINISHED = 1;

OPEN CURRENT_ROW;

GET_ACTION:
LOOP
    FETCH CURRENT_ROW INTO CURRENT_ROW_ID;

    IF FINISHED = 1 THEN
        LEAVE GET_ACTION;
    END IF;

    SET @CURRENT_P_ID := (SELECT ID_P FROM A WHERE ID = CURRENT_ROW_ID);

    SELECT a.ID_U, a.ID_R, a.A, a.FROMDATE, a.TODATE 
    INTO @ID_U, @ID_R, @A, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE
    FROM ASSIG a
    WHERE a.ID_G = @CURRENT_P_ID; # <- Query that returns 0 rows and terminates the cursor

    IF (@ID_U IS NOT NULL) THEN
        SET @ASSIG_ID := GENERATE_ID();
        INSERT INTO ASSIG
        VALUES (@ASSIG_ID,
                @G_ID,
                @ID_U,
                @ID_R,
                @A,
                @FROM_DATE,
                @TO_DATE);
    END IF;

    UPDATE A
    SET ID_P = @G_ID
    WHERE ID = CURRENT_ROW_ID;

END LOOP GET_ACTION;
CLOSE CURRENT_ROW;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The query inside the cursor returning 0 rows is exactly the definition of not found...

Comment: I'm aware of that. But what if I want to terminate the CURSOR only if the DECLARE ... CURSOR FOR ... query returns 0 rows?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still do not understand the difference between the two cases you are trying to describe

Comment: I've added a template of the cursor that I'm using with a comment where the cursor terminates

Comment: You may declare a variable, set it to differens values in different places of your code and analyze this variable value in the handler. This method allows to determine where, on what statement, the handler was triggered.